# Error con regla de tres en php

Tags: php

Tengo una regla de 3 simple cuyos numero provienen de una lista.

Este es el error

> Warning: Division by zero in /public_html/index.php on line 179

```
$a = $cont->rowCount(); //Total de activdades
$b = $contc->rowCount(); //Actividades resultas
$resultado = $b * 100 / $a;
```

la variable `$b` por el momento tiene el trae el valor `0` ya que no hay ninguna actividad resuelta y trate de hacer los siguiente:

```
if ($b =! 0) {
    $resultado = $b * 100 / $a;
}
```

pero el error es el mismo, no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: que valor le esta llegando a la variable `$a`? podrías agregar con que valor llega a la operación? por que ese error es por que dicha variable llega sin valor numérico asignado

Comment: claro, la variable $a tambien es `0`

Comment: por eso el error pues no es posible hacer la división entre cero

Comment: si, estoy viendo que hasta en la calculadora me da cero y como puedo resolverlo si en la base de datos no hay datos

Comment: pues el error es claro hasta que no le llega un número diferente a 0 ese error seguirá que mas que un error aparece como un warning

Comment: Es `if ($b != 0)` y no  `if ($b =! 0)`, saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Administralo mediante un `if/else` del modo siguiente

```
<?php

$a = 0; //Total de activdades
$b = 10; //Actividades resultas

if($a === 0){
    echo "No es posible obtener el resultado pues no hay actividades";
}else{
    echo $resultado = $b * 100 / $a;
}
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Dentro del `if` verificamos si el valor de `$a` es igual a 0
- En caso de ser positivo ese valor le indicamos que no podemos realizar la op. pues no hay actividades
- Dentro del `else` establecemos la operación pues en esta parte solo entrará la condición cuando el valor de `$a` sea diferente de 0

Aqui tienes la [documentación de divisonbyzero](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php)

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Puedes incluso hacer uso del operador ternario para reducir la cantidad de líneas del ejemplo que te proveí justo arriba quedando así

```
$resultado = ($a === 0) ? "No es posible la op." : $b * 100 / $a;

echo $resultado;
```

Comment: Claro y yo habia puesto si era distinto y sobre `$b` y no sobre `$a`. Gracias por el dato y el link, voy a leer un poco.

Answer (score 2):

Es que la variable que no puede valer cero no es la `$b`, sino la `$a`. Prueba así:

```
if ($a =! 0) {
    $resultado = $b * 100 / $a;
}
```

Recuerda, de Matemáticas, que:

- Cero, divido entre cualquier número, sigue siendo cero. No da ningún warning, esta operación está perfectamente definida.
- Cualquier número divido por cero, da infinito. En informática se representa como `NaN` (not a number), y no tenemos forma de operar con él porque es imposible almacenarlo en una posición de memoria.
- Cero dividido por cero es una indeterminación. Habría que irse al cálculo infinitesimal para determinar qué cero es más mayor, si el del numerador o el del denominador. En el primer caso, y siempre en el límite, el resultado sería infinito y, en el segundo, cero.

Comment: Claro yo lo habia hecho con la variable `$b` y en realidad tenia que hacerlo con la variable `$a` como tu lo indicas. No habia hecho el calculo y no entendia porque daba error. Muchas gracias David!

Comment: Si no necesitas usar la rama del `else` lo puedes resolver en una sola línea usando un [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) : `$resultado = $a?$b * 100 / $a:false;`